# Launch application before server completes startup

Tags: websphere-7

I have 2 apps on server: "Websphere Commerce" and "myapp". While Myapp inits, it needs to receive some data from WC using SOAP, however, until both apps are started, the common http port 9060 isn't listening.

There's a flag:

```
Enterprise Applications > * > Startup behavior
Startup order
Launch application before server completes startup
```

It's cleared for both apps. I thought, WAS would first report:

```
TCP Channel TCP_2 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9060.
Server server1 open for e-business
```

then start the apps, but it first starts them, then opens the port.

Then what does this flag do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this page [Startup behavior settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/urun_rapp_startup_behavior.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)

> Launch application before server completes startup
>
> Specifies whether the application must initialize fully **before** the
>   server starts. The default setting of false indicates that server
>   startup will not complete until the application starts.
>
> A setting of true informs the product that the application might start
>   on a background thread and thus **server startup might continue without
>   waiting for the application to start**. Thus, the **application might
>   not be ready for use** when the application server starts.

So it is other way around, server first ensures that applications are started and then opens port to allow traffic to them.